# Modifying skyscraper graph

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, bar-chart

For the following data:

```
require(ggplot2)
    ds <- read.table(header = TRUE, text ="
Coefficient model    value
          BIC   m0F 13
          AIC   m0F 12
     deviance   m0F 11
          BIC   m1F 12
          AIC   m1F 11
     deviance   m1F 10
          BIC   m2F 10
          AIC   m2F 9
     deviance   m2F 8                 
                 ")
print(ds)
```

I would like to produce a graph with model on the x-axis, the value on the y-axis and Coefficient mapped by color. I would like the mark to be a single line of the respective color, but so far could build it only with bar, which is suboptimal:

```
colorFit <- c("BIC"="#8da0cb", "AIC"="#fc8d62", "deviance"="#66c2a5") 

g <- ggplot2::ggplot(ds, aes(x= model, y=value, fill= Coefficient, group=model)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="identity", alpha=1) + #This line draw the distant skyscrapers
  scale_fill_manual(values=colorFit) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits= c("m0F","m1F","m2F")) +
  scale_y_continuous(label=scales::comma) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c( min(ds$value), max(ds$value) )) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL)) + 
  labs(x=NULL, y="Misfit")
g
```

[image]

### Question:

how do I replace the bars with a line corresponding to the value of each Coefficient? (the top of the bar graph). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this address what you want?  The first part primarily converts the discrete variable into a numeric variable.  The `ordered` part of the factor isn't necessary, but I like how it reinforces that it's being linearized on an axis.  The call to `factor()` is also a good chance to change the ordering if the alphabetic order doesn't match what you want.

```
barWidth <- .9
ds$modelF <- factor(ds$model, ordered=TRUE)
factorLevels <- levels(ds$modelF)
ds$modelID <- match(ds$modelF, factorLevels)
ds$x <- ds$modelID
ds$xstart <- ds$modelID - barWidth/2
ds$xend <- ds$modelID + barWidth/2
ds$label <- scales::comma(ds$value)
```

When you graph, make sure the factor variable hasn't changed since `factorLevels` was defined above.

```
ggplot2::ggplot(ds, aes(x=xstart, xend=xend, y=value, yend=value, color=Coefficient, label=label, group=model)) +
  geom_segment(size=2) +
  geom_text(aes(x=x), vjust=-.2, show_guide=FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values=colorFit) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=factorLevels) + #Force to have discrete labels, but make sure the factor hasn't changed since this assignment.
  scale_y_continuous(label=scales::comma) +
  labs(x=NULL, y="Misfit")
```

[image]

Comment: This is it! Thanks, just what I needed. The question was formulated poorly, i can see now. Thanks for playing the mentalist!